# javascript xpcom component to download weather underground weather data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpcom, weather, wunderground

I am building a javascript component for Firefox that will take in a zip code, and will return the current weather conditions.

[The sample code that weather underground uses jQuery](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples), but as I understand it, I cannot include this code in my javascript component, as javascript does not have the functionality to include other javascript files.

At any rate, I have built up my skeleton code. It takes in the zip code and builds up the url

(example: http://api.wunderground.com/api/e17115d7e24a448e/geolookup/conditions/q/22203.json)

I have tried downloading the data from that url, via the following method:

```
getWeatherByUrl: function(url)
{
    var persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD",Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.append("weather-forecaster.dat");
    var urlURI = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService).newURI(url, null, null);        
    persist.saveURI(urlURI,null,null,null,"",file);
    return url;
}
```

This should download the file to the user's profile directory. It indeed *does* create the file there. However, it does not look like it contains the json data from weather underground.

What exactly is going on? How would I download the file? I believe that there is a query going on when that url is passed to weather underground, but that shouldn't matter as the .json page is what gets spit out from them, right?

Is there a way to do this without downloading the file, but by streaming it and parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) to download this data:

```js
var request = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
request.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
request.addEventListener("load", function(event)
{
  var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  alert(data.response.version);
}, false);
request.send(null);
```